# Webpack and sass - not loaded

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

I have a webpack setup with `sass-loader` etc. (code below). There is this weird thing happening with my scss file, which looks like this:

```
nav {
  //...
  // This does work
  ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  // This does too
  img {
    width: 48px;
  }
  // This doesn't work (and the img above has the class of logo
  .logo {
    width: 48px;
  }
}
```

What might be causing this? It's really hard to debug and I can see the `scss` file in Chrome showing me output like this (so it should work)

```
nav img {
    width: 48px; }

nav .logo {
    width: 48px; }
```

**Webpack with happypack loaders**

```
happyPackPlugin({
          name: 'happypack-devclient-css',
          loaders: [
            'classnames-loader',
            'style-loader',
            {
              path: 'css-loader',
              query: {
                sourceMap: true,
                modules: true,
                importLoaders: 1,
                localIdentName,
              },
            },
            { path: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
              },
            },
            {
              path: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                outputStyle: 'expanded',
                sourceMap: true,
              },
            },
          ],
        })
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen that isn't happening? You are expecting your `.nav .logo` rules to apply and they aren't? Are they not showing up in the inspector? etc.

Comment: Yes. They are not showing in the inspector, but I can also see there that the file with styles is loaded.

Comment: You should post the relevant HTML, might help